# Capture exception in python

Tags: python

```
def makeFeatureVec(words, model, num_features):
    # Function to average all of the word vectors in a given
    # paragraph
    #
    # Pre-initialize an empty numpy array (for speed)
    featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,),dtype="float32")
    #
    nwords = 0.
    # 
    # Index2word is a list that contains the names of the words in 
    # the model's vocabulary. Convert it to a set, for speed 
    index2word_set = set(model.index2word)
    #
    # Loop over each word in the review and, if it is in the model's
    # vocaublary, add its feature vector to the total
    for word in words:
        if word in index2word_set :
            nwords = nwords + 1.
            featureVec = np.add(featureVec,model[word])
    # 
    # Divide the result by the number of words to get the average
    if nwords == 0 :
        return -1
    featureVec = np.divide(featureVec,nwords)
    return featureVec
```

Above function calculates the feature vector by just taking the average of feature vectors of words. But it will throw an error if number of words is equal to 0, and so I put the if condition to handle that thing. But now I am facing issues when I am calling this function in the following way :

```
feature = makeFeatureVec(words, model, int(num_features))  
if feature != -1 :
      docs_feature_vec.append(feature)
```

Following is the error traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier.py", line 161, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "classifier.py", line 159, in main
    classify(train_file, model_file, flag, num_features)
  File "classifier.py", line 144, in classify
    data,label = create_feature_vector_docs(train_file, model_file, flag, num_features)
  File "classifier.py", line 94, in create_feature_vector_docs
    if feature != -1 :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Please include the error traceback.

Comment: what is the error thrown??

Comment: I'd recommend returning `None` rather than `-1` on failure.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to check an array against an int

Comment: How to handle it, if return value is -1

Comment: if you return `None` instead of `-1`, you can just `if feature is not None:` . (Also, uh, I think returning `None` here is more pythonic.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Rather than figuring out how to make it work with -1, ask yourself if -1 is what should be returned in the first place. Consider how the `!=` is implemented with the array being returned.

Answer (score 2):

To handle errors in python you must use `try` and `except`

```
try:
    if feature != -1:
        doSomething()
except Exception: 
    doSomethingElse()
```

I **would not** recommend this solution for what you are doing though.

In my opinion, you shouldn't `return -1` instead of an `array` in the first place.

I'd return `None`, then use

```
if feature is not None:
    doSomething()
else:
    doSomethingElse()
```

In the `try` code, you would be basically expecting an `Exception` to occur.

This isn't good practice, and `Exceptions` should only really occur when you're not expecting them.